# Não envia html pelo email mail php

Tags: email, phpmailer, php

Criei um codigo para enviar e-mail, porém não enviar nada de html, o meu codigo é

```
<?php
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $emailenvio = "noreply@sis.colegioaplic.com.br";
        $subject = "Recuperar a senha!";
        $img = "
        <img src='http://sis.colegioaplic.com.br/images/upload/empresa/ec4c92255d6f28fb784d83119b0052bc.png'>
        ";
        $imagem_nome="http://sis.colegioaplic.com.br/images/upload/empresa/ec4c92255d6f28fb784d83119b0052bc.png"; 
        $arquivo=fopen($imagem_nome,'r'); 
        $message ="
        <html>
            $arquivo
            Olá :)
            Agora você pode recuperar sua senha!
            Agora você pode usar sua nova senha clicando no botão abaixo.
        </html> 
        ";
        $message = wordwrap($message,70);


        $header = "MIME-Version: 1.1\n";
        $header .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
        $header .= "From: $emailenvio\n";
        $header .= "Return-Path: $email_remetente\n"; // return-path
        $envio = mail($email, $subject, $message, $header);


        if($envio){
            echo "Mensagem Enviada com sucesso!";
        } else {
            echo "ERRO AO ENVIAR E-MAIL!";
        }
    ?>
```

O que recebeu no e-mail é

> ```
>                     <html>
>                             Resource id #3
>                             OlÃ¡ :)
>                             Agora vocÃª pode recuperar sua senha!
>                             Agora vocÃª pode usar sua nova senha clicando no botÃ£o abaixo.
>                     </html>
> ```

o que pode está errado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitua:

```
$header .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
```

por:

```
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

A linha `Content-Type: text/html` diz ao *mailer* e ao destinatário que o email contém HTML.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado

Comment: @DanielAlencarSouza Não se esqueça aceitar a resposta como correta para sua questão.